# How can I join a string list in Groovy using a different separator for the last item

Tags: string, list, collections, groovy

I would like to join a list of strings for user output. The separator between each string shall be a `','` except for the last element where the separator shall be `'and'`.

For example:

```
def a = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
println a.joinWithDifferentLast(', ', ' and ');
// output: one, two and three
```

How can I implement such a join function in Groovy? Would be nice if it can handle the case with one element (no separator), two elements (last separator) and multiple elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this as well:

```
def joinWithDifferentLast( List list, String others, String last ) {
  def start = list.take( list.size() - 1 ).join( others )
  def end   = list.drop( list.size() - 1 )[ 0 ]
  if( start ) {
    [ start, last, end ].join()
  }
  else {
    end as String ?: ''
  }
}

assert ''           == joinWithDifferentLast( [],          ', ', ' and ' )
assert '1'          == joinWithDifferentLast( [ 1 ],       ', ', ' and ' )
assert '1 and 2'    == joinWithDifferentLast( [ 1, 2 ],    ', ', ' and ' )
assert '1, 2 and 3' == joinWithDifferentLast( [ 1, 2, 3 ], ', ', ' and ' )
```

Answer (score 2):

For fun, I tried to make something a little easier to read:

```
def static joinWithDifferentLast(List list, String firstJoin, String lastJoin) {
    switch (list?.size() ?: 0) {
        case 0:
            return ''
        case 1:
            return list.head() as String
        default:
            return list.init().join(firstJoin) + lastJoin + list.last()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List.metaClass.joinWithDifferentLast { a, b ->
    delegate.join(a).reverse().replaceFirst(a.reverse(),b.reverse()).reverse()
}

def a = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
println a.joinWithDifferentLast(',',' and ') //prints one,two and three

assert ''           == [].joinWithDifferentLast(' , ', ' and ' )
assert '1'          == [ 1 ].joinWithDifferentLast( ', ', ' and ' )
assert '1 and 2'    == [ 1, 2 ].joinWithDifferentLast( ', ', ' and ' )
assert '1, 2 and 3' == [ 1, 2, 3 ].joinWithDifferentLast(', ', ' and ' ) 
assert '1 %ac 2 %ac 3 %ac 4 %ac 5 %bi 6' == [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ].joinWithDifferentLast(' %ac ', ' %bi ' )
```

would be my first brute-force and naïve (but corrected) guess :-D

```
List.metaClass.joinWithDifferentLast { a, b ->
    def l = delegate.size() 
    delegate[0..l-2].join(a) + b + delegate[l-1]
}
```

is a bit less 'reversal' but need securisation regarding the size() of the list

Comment: The first function unfortunately does not work in case of separators with length > 1 (e.g. when you use `', '`). Have not tested the second one.

Comment: i've edited accordingly, since I stucked to your example in the first row

Comment: @Grooveek This also has problems if the last element of the list contains the first separator, ie: `assert [ 'pizza', 'bacon', 'sausage, beans and chips'].joinWithDifferentLast() == 'pizza, bacon, sausage and beans and chips'` as you can see, the `sausage` element has changed, and there is no `and` separator.